# Have OpenGL Render while cursor in GLUT UI

Tags: opengl, interface, render, glut

I have a main window which has both a glut UI in the top 10% of the screen, and the openGL world in the bottom 90% of the screen. Every time my cursor starts hovering over the GLUT portion, openGL rendering will freeze. It resumes only when the cursor exits the GLUT area.

This is because as long as the cursor is hovering over the GLUT area, presumably glutIdleFunc is never called because glut is not "idle", so openGL stuff is not rendered.

I already tried making a new unrelated thread that just calls the display code and/or glutPostRedisplay but I got a framerate of whopping 20 fps as opposed to the 100+ fps the normal way. I don't know exactly why. (In this test I also disabled glutIdleFunc so there is no idle func, just the separate thread calling the display)

Ways to get around this (other than "stop using glut" which I might do in the future but for now I would like a temporary solution)?

Comment: How are you setting up these two different parts of your screen so that, in fact, they are "separate" as far as GLUT is concerned?

Comment: GLUT doesn't *have* a UI. So how are you building this UI? Are you using GLUI (which uses GLUT but is itself not GLUT)?

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using GLUI, and the subwindow is created using  GLUI *glui = GLUI_Master.create_glui_subwindow(main_window, GLUI_SUBWINDOW_TOP);

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I was having a similar issue and wanted to share how I solved it.

Basically, in your idle function, you should manually set the window to your normal window ID. Thanks to Joel Davis' HexPlanet code ( https://github.com/joeld42/hexplanet/ ) for demonstrating this:

```
void glut_Idle( void )
{
  // According to the GLUT specification, the current window is 
  // undefined during an idle callback.  So we need to explicitly change
  // it if necessary
  if ( glutGetWindow() != g_glutMainWin ) 
  {
    glutSetWindow(g_glutMainWin);  
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Worked for me! Not sure why my glutPostRedisplay works in the GLUI callback but not onIdle when mousing over GLUI, but this fixed it not working inside my onIdle!

Answer (score 0):

Create a callback for passive motion func:

```
void passiveMouseFunc(int,int){
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

And register it using:

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc(passiveMouseFunc);
```

Comment: Well unfortunately: 
1. that will not work when the user's mouse is not moving
2. glut seems to treat ui portion and opengl portion of screen as different windows so the glutPostRedisplay only refreshes the ui portion anyways.